# sails/waterline remove key

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm maybe just having a bit of a brain freeze here, but I'm stuck on a silly issue. I've a angular/sails app, which allows a user to fill in a form, and save their progress on the way so they can come back at a later date.

The initial Model is created the usual way via create (POST), and then afterwards, and changes made are via update (PUT). The thing is, when I delete a key and save (i.e. a user clears a input field, causing angular to actually remove the key from the object), it doesn't actually delete that key, as the nature of an update (especially in sails) is that it only affects the key that you have in your payload, and leaves the others as they are.

Let me try to explain further....

Created record....

```
{
    first : "Dan",
    last : "Knight"
    age : 40
}
```

Update payload (PUT)....

```
{
   first : "Danny"
   // 'last' field not present as was cleared in form
   age : 40 
}
```

result....

```
{
    first : "Danny",
    last : "Knight"
    age : 40
}
```

desired result....

```
{
    first : "Danny",
    age : 40
}
```

I realise that I should probably be setting to null instead of deleting the field, but the only way I can thing to do that is set up a $watch for each form field, and set to null if I detect "" (empty string), Iand I really don't want to set up dozens of watchers as seems messy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`lodash.defaults`](https://lodash.com/docs#defaults) in your sails model/controller to ensure that missing fields have the desired default value

```
var defaults = {
  first: null,
  last: null,
  age: null
};

_.defaults(resBody, defaults);
```